# Failure to install TexLive on Windows 8

Tags: installing

I am trying to install TexLive 2012 on Windows 8 64 bit with the following results.

> Loading - See URL below
>   Installing TeX Live 2012 from: See URL below
>
> Platform: win32 => 'Windows'
>   Distribution: net  (downloading)
>
> Using URL: http://tezcatl.fciencias.unam.mx/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
>
> Directory for temporary files: C:/Users/jonathan/AppData/Local/Temp
>
> Installing [0001/2603, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
>
> TLDownload::get_file: response error:
>    500 Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference
>
> permanent server connection set up, but downloading did not succeed!Retrying with wget.
>
> Downloading http://tezcatl.fciencias.unam.mx/tex->archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/12many.tar.xz did not succeed.
>
> Installation failed.
>   Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.

I thought that the problem might be with the repository but when I tried to use --repository to select an alternate repository the flag was ignored and the problematic repository was used. Any ideas as to wher to proceed from here? I ould find nothing useful in the mailing list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I finally managed to get install-tl to accept a different repository which worked without problems.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the installation once again—without any parameters, so the installer will get a mirror automatically (By just using the `install-tl.bat` or `install-tl-advanced.bat`)? If this happens with more mirrors and not only with that specific, it could be a bug together with Windows 8. If this is true, I think it would be best, you post your bugreport to the TeX Live-Mailinglist texlive@tug.org, as I don't know, how many TeX Live maintainers are reading TeX.sx regularly.

Information about the list texlive@tug.org is provided by [TUG](https://www.tug.org/texlive/lists.html).

There is also some special advice for [Windows](https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html), maybe there is a hint helping you.